# I can't find my edit profile button in my account's page

Tags: discussion, profile-page, stackexchange.com

After clicking on my username, then clicking on Network Profile I get this:
[image]

I can't change my email, or profile picture or anything. Could you please help me? I'm trying to enable myself to login to this account via a particular email and not have to log in using Google+ account.

Comment: Do it from one of the Q&A sites (like this one) and not from stackexchange.com - the login information will be synced.

Answer (score 0):

In your profile page go to

Edit profile & settings which will open [this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current) in your case.

Change what you want and click <kbd>save and copy changes to all communities</kbd>.

One more way to add new login id is to click on my login it will show you your current logins and ask you to add new id if you want to add more login id.

Comment: Abhishek - the problem is he is looking at the wrong profile page...